# AWS step function does not add next step to EMR cluster when current step fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

I have setup a state machine from AWS step function that will create a EMR cluster, add few emr steps and then terminate the cluster. This is working fine as long as all the steps are running to completion without any errors. If a step fails, despite adding a catch to proceed to the next step, this is not happening. Whenever a step fails, the step is marked as caught(in ornage color in graph) but the next step is marked as cancelled.

This is my step function definition if it helps:

```
{
  "StartAt": "MyEMR-SMFlowContainer-beta",
  "States": {
    "MyEMR-SMFlowContainer-beta": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "End": true,
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "CreateClusterStep-feature-generation-cluster-beta",
          "States": {
            "CreateClusterStep-feature-generation-cluster-beta": {
              "Next": "Step-SuccessfulJobOne",
              "Type": "Task",
              "ResultPath": "$.Cluster.1.CreateClusterTask",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:createCluster.sync",
              "Parameters": {
                "Instances": {
                  "Ec2SubnetIds": [
                    "subnet-*******345fd38423"
                  ],
                  "InstanceCount": 2,
                  "KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps": true,
                  "MasterInstanceType": "m4.xlarge",
                  "SlaveInstanceType": "m4.xlarge"
                },
                "JobFlowRole": "MyEMR-emrInstance-beta-EMRInstanceRole",
                "Name": "emr-step-fail-handle-test-cluster",
                "ServiceRole": "MyEMR-emr-beta-EMRRole",
                "Applications": [
                  {
                    "Name": "Spark"
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "Hadoop"
                  }
                ],
                "AutoScalingRole": "MyEMR-beta-FeatureG-CreateClusterStepfeature-NJB2UG1J1EWB",
                "Configurations": [
                  {
                    "Classification": "spark-env",
                    "Configurations": [
                      {
                        "Classification": "export",
                        "Properties": {
                          "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "LogUri": "s3://MyEMR-beta-feature-createclusterstepfeature-1jpp1wp3dfn04/emr/logs/",
                "ReleaseLabel": "emr-5.32.0",
                "VisibleToAllUsers": true
              }
            },
            "Step-SuccessfulJobOne": {
              "Next": "Step-AlwaysFailingJob",
              "Catch": [
                {
                  "ErrorEquals": [
                    "States.ALL"
                  ],
                  "Next": "Step-AlwaysFailingJob"
                }
              ],
              "Type": "Task",
              "TimeoutSeconds": 7200,
              "ResultPath": "$.ClusterStep.SuccessfulJobOne.AddSparkTask",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep.sync",
              "Parameters": {
                "ClusterId.$": "$.Cluster.1.CreateClusterTask.ClusterId",
                "Step": {
                  "Name": "SuccessfulJobOne",
                  "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
                  "HadoopJarStep": {
                    "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
                    "Args": [
                      "spark-submit",
                      "--deploy-mode",
                      "client",
                      "--master",
                      "yarn",
                      "--conf",
                      "spark.logConf=true",
                      "--class",
                      "com.test.sample.core.EMRJobRunner",
                      "s3://my-****-bucket/jars/77/my-****-bucketBundleJar-1.0.jar",
                      "--JOB_NUMBER",
                      "1",
                      "--JOB_KEY",
                      "SuccessfulJobOne"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "Step-AlwaysFailingJob": {
              "Next": "Step-SuccessfulJobTwo",
              "Catch": [
                {
                  "ErrorEquals": [
                    "States.ALL"
                  ],
                  "Next": "Step-SuccessfulJobTwo"
                }
              ],
              "Type": "Task",
              "TimeoutSeconds": 7200,
              "ResultPath": "$.ClusterStep.AlwaysFailingJob.AddSparkTask",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep.sync",
              "Parameters": {
                "ClusterId.$": "$.Cluster.1.CreateClusterTask.ClusterId",
                "Step": {
                  "Name": "AlwaysFailingJob",
                  "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
                  "HadoopJarStep": {
                    "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
                    "Args": [
                      "spark-submit",
                      "--deploy-mode",
                      "client",
                      "--master",
                      "yarn",
                      "--conf",
                      "spark.logConf=true",
                      "--class",
                      "com.test.sample.core.EMRJobRunner",
                      "s3://my-****-bucket/jars/77/my-****-bucketBundleJar-1.0.jar",
                      "--JOB_NUMBER",
                      "2",
                      "--JOB_KEY",
                      "AlwaysFailingJob"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "Step-SuccessfulJobTwo": {
              "Next": "TerminateClusterStep-feature-generation-cluster-beta",
              "Catch": [
                {
                  "ErrorEquals": [
                    "States.ALL"
                  ],
                  "Next": "TerminateClusterStep-feature-generation-cluster-beta"
                }
              ],
              "Type": "Task",
              "TimeoutSeconds": 7200,
              "ResultPath": "$.ClusterStep.SuccessfulJobTwo.AddSparkTask",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep.sync",
              "Parameters": {
                "ClusterId.$": "$.Cluster.1.CreateClusterTask.ClusterId",
                "Step": {
                  "Name": "DeviceJob",
                  "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
                  "HadoopJarStep": {
                    "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
                    "Args": [
                      "spark-submit",
                      "--deploy-mode",
                      "client",
                      "--master",
                      "yarn",
                      "--conf",
                      "spark.logConf=true",
                      "--class",
                      "com.test.sample.core.EMRJobRunner",
                      "s3://my-****-bucket/jars/77/my-****-bucketBundleJar-1.0.jar",
                      "--JOB_NUMBER",
                      "3",
                      "--JOB_KEY",
                      "SuccessfulJobTwo"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "TerminateClusterStep-feature-generation-cluster-beta": {
              "End": true,
              "Type": "Task",
              "ResultPath": null,
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:terminateCluster.sync",
              "Parameters": {
                "ClusterId.$": "$.Cluster.1.CreateClusterTask.ClusterId"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "TimeoutSeconds": 43200
}
```

Can somebody please advice on how I can catch a failure in step and ignore it add the next step.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I noticed you wrap all states inside a parallel state. Is there any reason for that? Or maybe you have more branches but for simplicity you posted a simplified version here? Did you test without that parallel state?

Comment: I have other branches which I didn't paste here for simplicity. I tried removing that before, but didn't help. I have posted the reason for the issue as an answer. I have resolved the issue,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was because I was not specifying the resultPath in catch properties. This was causing the resultPath to be overwritten by the catch block since default value of resultPath is $. Next step is not able to get the cluster information since that is overwritten and hence got cancelled.

```
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "Next": "Step-SuccessfulJobTwo"
        }
      ],
```

Once I updated the catch to have a proper result path, it was working as expected.

```
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "Next": "Step-SuccessfulJobTwo",
          "ResultPath": "$.ClusterStep.SuccessfulJobOne.AddSparkTask.Error",
        }
      ],
```